# Again the bug in histogram from matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I have a list of real numbers between `[-pi,pi]`. For some strange reason, when I want to make the corresponding histogram I get:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.hist(phase[:195])
ValueError: 'list' argument must have no negative elements
```

This is nonsense, since even the first 195 elements in my list are positive numbers. Any idea what is going on?

It is even stranger that `plt.hist[:194]` is plotted without problem.

EDIT:

I'm almost sure that this is definitely a bug. My data is:

```
array([ 2.11185959,  1.04346977,  1.05034218, ..., -2.24530117,
   -2.24823866, -0.89629148], dtype=float128)
```

and the problem is in the type that I am using (which is a little stupid, since this quantity is calculated using  `np.arctan2`). On the other hand,

```
plt.hist(np.array(phase, dtype=np.float64))
```

works perfectly fine.

Comment: How is this `float128` array generated? Why not use `float64`?

Comment: Well, it is generated I think because I read my files using  `np.longdouble`.

Comment: So `a = np.arctan2(1,1)
print(a.dtype)` gives `float128` on your machine?

Comment: No, in this case is `float64`, but if you consider `longdouble` then you have `float128`.

Comment: I see. So you may create a feature request, asking for matplotlib to fully support float128, but I would consider chances quite low that anyone is actually willing to implement it, as the benefit is close to zero.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot.